# Duplicate Infopath 2013 form to multiple new lists in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I created a form which links to a list and works great. I want to duplicate the form and list multiple times. What are the steps I need to take?

I want to save myself from recreating the form over and over.

Answer (score 0):

To duplicate the list and form, you could save the list as template and then create the list based on the list template.

Go to the list which you want to duplicate->list settings-> Permissions and Management->Save list as template and select “Include Content”.

After the list template is created successfully, then you could go to site contents->add an app->select the list template which is created by you.

After all, it will create the same list as the list template.

More reference:

[Manage list templates.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393)